# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objenesis/ObjenesisStd with Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I don't know why I have that error with mockito

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.<init>(ClassImposterizer.java:36)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.<clinit>(ClassImposterizer.java:29)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.isTypeMockable(MockCreationValidator.java:17)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:21)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:133)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:127)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:50)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
at fr.oap.SubscriptionTest.testGetSubscriptionById(SubscriptionFactoryTest.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objenesis.ObjenesisStd
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 29 more
```

About my class of Test is like this :

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import fr.aop.subscription.AbstractSubscription;
public class SubscriptionTest extends TestCase {
@Test
public void testGetSubscriptionById() {
    ArgumentCaptor<AbstractSubscription> 
arg=ArgumentCaptor.forClass(AbstractSubscription.class);        
     Subscription objMock=Mockito.mock(Subscription.class);        
    Mockito.when(objMock.getSubscribById(1)).thenReturn(arg.getValue());
}
}
```

And about the method getSubscribById whitch is in the class Subscription:

```
@Override
public AbstractSubscription getSubscriptionById(final Integer id) {
    this.log.debug("BEGIN: getSubscriptionById id = " + id);
    AbstractSubscription obj = null;
    if (id != null) {
        final StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("select c from AbstractSubscription c ");

        try {
            queryString.append("where c.id = :id");
            Query query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString.toString());
            query = query.setParameter("id", id);
            obj = (AbstractSubscription) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (final Exception exc) {

        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

when I instanciate the Subcription class it demand me the connection to the database, that's why I want to escape this and looking for a solution like mockito

Comment: just add objenesis in your classpath

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ClassNotFoundException` is result of a class loader that is not able to load a particular class.

In your case Mockito has a transitive dependency to Objenesis (it needs Objenesis for correct behavior). You are most likely trying to execute your test with Mockito on test class path, but without Objenesis.

You need to add Objenesis to your test class path.

For maven projects, be sure that:

1. you have declared Mockito as test dependency

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
       <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.10.19</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. to run a particular test from the command line execute

   ```
   mvn test -Dtest=fullyQualifedNameToYourTestClass
   ```

Comment: And how it's possible to do that

Comment: How are you running your tests? Using Maven, Ant, from command line?

Comment: i have a maven project but i make a right clic on my classtest and i choose run as JunitTest

Comment: I updated the comment. You should have the Mockito test dependency in your POM and not excluded the Objenesis. If that does not work, it is probably an IDE bug. It should be always working from the command line.

Answer (score 6):

You can try adding the mockito-all artifact instead of mockito-core, it works since version 1.9.5

Comment: mockito-all is deprecated: 
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2

_Mockito does not produce the mockito-all artifact anymore ; this one was primarily aimed at ant users, and contained other dependencies. We felt it was time to move on and remove such artifacts as they cause problems in dependency management system like maven or gradle._

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error of:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objenesis/ObjenesisStd

when I was running a test in a new project that was using Mockito.

Turns out in addition to adding the Mockito Dependencies I also had to add the Objenesis dependency. All I need to do was add the below dependency to my pom.xml and it all worked perfectly fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
    <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in an Android project using gradle.

Like @Popeye did for maven, I added the following line to build.gradle, among dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'org.objenesis:objenesis:2.3'
```

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue with the version of mockito-core 2.22.0.

After investigation it seems that the jar of objenesis was corrupted in my maven repository...

Just a `rm -rf .m2/repository/org/objenesis` is enough

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I deleted the mockito folder from my local repository and re-run the build, and it worked.